# Usage of "language" for a document

Tags: word-usage

What is the common way to use *language* for documents?

- My document language is Persian
- My document language is in Persian
- My document is in Persian
- My document's language is Persian..,

Comment: As a suggestion: Are there other versions of this document and you want to say that what is the language in yours ? Or you want to say that I prepared a document which is in Persian language. I think It can help who answers the question.

Comment: @Cardinal I mean I prepared it in Persian.

Answer (score 7):

**The document is in Persian** would be idiomatic spoken English.

**The language of the document is Persian** would also fly.

"Document language" is not ungrammatical, but I do find it to be unidiomatic. It strikes my ear as techno-speak, the sort of thing we'd read in a specification produced by a standards body.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-specify-the-document-language-using-the-lang-attribute/

Comment: Exactly. Techno-speak. "...why it's a good idea to declare your document language and how to use the lang attribute correctly."  Essentially, "document language" follows the conventions that are usually in effect when choosing property names and the names of database columns.